# How to use tableViewCell to add view to viewController?

Tags: swift

I have a tableViewCell that holds some functions for each cell in a tableview. I want one of these functions to present an `activityIndicator` to the view to prevent user interaction with the app until the function is done. Normally this can be done by using:

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
func exampleFunc(){
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 50,height: 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center //can't be used as self.view doesn't exist because self is a tableviewCell
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator) //also can't be used
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        if x<y{
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() 
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }

    }
```

The problem with this is that the `self.view.center` cannot be used as this function is housed in the tableViewCell and therefore `self` is referring to the tableViewCell and so a `self.view` is not usable. How can I add this activity indicator to the tableView housing the tableViewCell despite it being in the `tableViewCell`?

Comment: Why put the code for displaying the activity indicator in the cell, and not in the table view itself?

Comment: you can use notification or delegation while keeping the activity indicator in the viewController and posting the notification from tableViewCell

Comment: @NRitH because the functions for all of the buttons in each cell are held in the cell... and it is those buttons that I would like to use to display the activityindicator

Comment: @saroshmirza how would I use delegation to do this?

Comment: Hi @AlekPiasecki, not exactly the same problem but a similar situation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582740/how-to-use-delegates-to-communicate-data-from-a-custom-cell-to-a-label-in-the-pa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol, such as:

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate { 
    func showActivityIndicator()
}
```

Then in your UITableViewCell create a reference to a MyTableViewCellDelegate:

```
var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
```

Then make your controller conform to your new protocol, ex:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyTableViewCellDelegate {

...

    func showActivityIndicator() {
        // implement your ActivityIndicator logic here
    }
}
```

Set your cells' delegate to be your controller. Then whenever your cell needs to show an ActivityIndicator all you need to call is:

```
delegate?.showActivityIndicator()
```