# UITableCell value not passing to function within UIViewController Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table that is populated by a search function. There are two buttons within the cell, a checkmark to say yes to a user and an X to say no.  There is an insert function that inserts the selection into the database. Unfortunately the value from the table is not being passed to the insert function. Within the insert function, I'm using guestusername.text which is the name of the label in my cell. I'm getting the error 'Use of unresolved identifier guestusername'. I've tried everything I can think of, code below.

```
class MyShotsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var guest = [AnyObject]()
    var avas = [UIImage]()
    var valueToPass:String!
    var revieweduser:String!
    var age = [AnyObject]()
    var city = [AnyObject]()
    var state = [AnyObject]()
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var cell: MyShotsCell?
    var index = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        doSearch("")
    }

    // cell numb
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return guest.count
    }

    // cell config
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyShotsCell

        // get one by one user related inf from users var
        let guest2 = guest[indexPath.row]
        let ava = avas[indexPath.row]        

        // shortcuts
        let guestname = guest2["username"] as? AnyObject
        let age = guest2["age"]
        let city = guest2["city"] as? String
        let state = guest2["state"] as? String

        // refer str to cell obj
        cell.guestusername.text = guestname as! String
        cell.ageLbl.text = (NSString(format: "%@", age as! CVarArg) as String)
        cell.cityLbl.text = city
        cell.stateLbl.text = state
        cell.avaImg.image = ava as? UIImage

        return cell
    }

    // search / retrieve users
    public func doSearch(_ guestusername : String) {
        // shortcuts
        let username = user?["username"] as! String        
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx.php")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url) // create request to work with users.php file

        request.httpMethod = "POST" // method of passing inf to users.php

        let body = "revieweduser=\(username)" // body that passes inf to users.php

        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8) // convert str to utf8 str - supports all languages

        // launch session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // getting main queue of proceeding inf to communicate back, in another way it will do it in background
            // and user will no see changes :)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if error == nil {                        
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        // clean up
                        self.guest.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.avas.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        // delcare new secure var to store json
                        guard let parseJSON = json else {
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }

                        guard let parseUSERS = parseJSON["users"] else {
                            print(parseJSON["message"] ?? [NSDictionary]())
                            return
                        }

                        self.guest = parseUSERS as! [AnyObject]
                        print(self.guest)

                        // for i=0; i < users.count; i++
                        for i in 0 ..< self.guest.count {
                            // getting path to ava file of user
                            let ava = self.guest[i]["ava"] as? String

                            let revieweduser = self.guest[i]["username"] as? String
                            let age = (NSString(format: "%@", self.guest[i]["age"] as! CVarArg) as String)
                            let city = self.guest[i]["city"] as? String
                            let state = self.guest[i]["state"] as? String

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    } catch {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            let message = "\(error)"
                            appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                        })
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = error!.localizedDescription
                        appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                    })
                    return
                }
            })

            } .resume()
    }

    // custom body of HTTP request to upload image file
    func createBodyWithParams(_ parameters: [String: String]?, boundary: String) -> Data {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        return body as Data
    }

    func insertShot(_ rating : String) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        let reviewer = user?["username"] as! String

        // url path to php file
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.xxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // param to be passed to php file
        let param = [
            "user" : reviewer,
            "revieweduser" : cell?.guestusername.text,
            "rating" : rating
            ] as [String : Any]

        // body
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // ... body
        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParams(param as? [String : String], boundary: boundary)

        // launch session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // get main queu to communicate back to user
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if error == nil {
                    do {
                        // json containes $returnArray from php
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        // declare new var to store json inf
                        guard let parseJSON = json else {
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }

                        // get message from $returnArray["message"]
                        let message = parseJSON["message"]
                        //print(message)

                        // if there is some message - post is made
                        if message != nil {

                            // reset UI
                            // self.msgTxt.text = ""

                            // switch to another scene
                            //self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
                            _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        // get main queue to communicate back to user
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            let message = "\(error)"
                            appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                        })
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    // get main queue to communicate back to user
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = error!.localizedDescription
                        appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                    })
                    return
                }
            })
            }.resume()
        return
    }

    @IBAction func yesBtn_clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.insertShot("Yes")
    }

    @IBAction func noBtn_clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.insertShot("No")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an insert function.  It's called func insertShot.  It's there towards the bottom of the code

Comment: Insertshot is being called within the IBAction buttons

Comment: Yes they are being triggered.  The issue is that the value within the label.text is not being accessed by this function.

Comment: Within insert I'm using guestusername.text which is the name of the label in my cell.  I'm getting the error 'Use of unresolved identifier guestusername'

Comment: Yes that is the problem line. My apologies, in the event the issue was caused by something else I didn't want to call it out and have a possible solution overlooked.

Comment: The problem hasn't been solved. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Be aware that the property `cell` and the variable `cell` in `cellForRow` is **not** the same object. And - as always – basically never get data from the view (cell), get it from the model (data source array).

Comment: The value is returning nil thus preventing the insert due to the conditions set.

Comment: Take time to learn TabelViewCell and Delegate Pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582740/how-to-use-delegates-to-communicate-data-from-a-custom-cell-to-a-label-in-the-pa